# VB.NET populating multiple datagriviews with MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Ihave a form with 4 tabs, each containing a datagridview. i want to populate each of these grids with different tables from my database, but the results of the queries keep on accumulating, until the final table contains the reults of 4 queries.
Here's my code:

```
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT* from venue"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset)

        query = "SELECT* FROM Decoration"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView2.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset)

        query = "SELECT* FROM food_drink"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView3.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset)

        query = "SELECT* FROM Entertainment"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView4.DataSource = bsource

        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

When i change it so that each query has its own datatable(dbdataset) i just get all datagridviews displaying the results of the final query.

```
Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT* from venue"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset1)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset1)

        query = "SELECT* FROM Decoration"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset2)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset2
        DataGridView2.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset2)

        query = "SELECT* FROM food_drink"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset3)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset3
        DataGridView3.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset3)

        query = "SELECT* FROM Entertainment"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)

        SDA.SelectCommand = command
        SDA.Fill(dbdataset4)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset4
        DataGridView4.DataSource = bsource
        SDA.Update(dbdataset4)

        mysqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: thats because you keep adding the query results to the same dataset (`dbdataset`).  you probably want to put the results each in a new datatable and bind each to its DGV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can shrink that code way down. Use multiple queries in the command by separating them with semi-colon and each will load into a DataTable. Then bind your grids to the correct datatable:

```
Try
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "SELECT* from venue;SELECT* FROM Decoration;SELECT* FROM food_drink;SELECT* FROM Entertainment;"
    SDA.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
    SDA.Fill(dbdataset)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables(0)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables(1)
    DataGridView3.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables(2)
    DataGridView4.DataSource = dbdataset.Tables(3)

    mysqlconn.Close()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    mysqlconn.Dispose()
End Try
```

You could also create 4 bindingsources and bind to those instead of directly to the Tables. Also you should Dispose of the connection and command.

Comment: Ahhh, you beat me to it. I was going to suggest the dataset Tables technique. Haha. Anyhow, no need for me to answer this. Gonna upvote your answer.

Comment: Where does the 'dbdataset.tables(0)' and so on, come from? When i type in the code, i get the message "Tables is not a member of system.data.datatable".

Comment: I inferred that your `dbdataset` variable was a DataSet, not a DataTable. Make `dbdataset` a DataSet or make a new one. But the code I have shown assumes you are filling a DataSet with tables, not filling one DataTable at a time.